# Elegant Way To Generate Composite Permutations in C++

Tags: c++, stl, permutation

I have a class Test which contains two vectors of a Letter class, a user defined type for which the less-than operator (<) has been implemented. How can I best generate all possible permutations of Test?

```
class Test
{
  vector<Letter> letter_box_a;
  vector<Letter> letter_box_b;
}
```

So if letter_box_a  contains the letters A and B and letter_box_b contains C and D the valid permutations of Test would be (AB)(CD), (BA)(CD), (AB)(DC) and (BA)(DC).

Although I am able to brute force it, I was trying to write a better (more elegant/efficient) function which would internally call  std::next_permutation on the underlying containers allowing me to do

```
Test test;
while (test.set_next_permutation())
{
    // Do the stuff
}
```

but it appears to be a bit trickier than I first anticipated. I don't necessarily need an STL solution but would like an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you could do something like

```
bool Test::set_next_permutation() {
    auto &a = letter_box_a, &b = letter_box_b;  // entirely to shorten the next line
    return std::next_permutation(a.start(), a.end()) || std::next_permutation(b.start(), b.end());
}
```

(Of course, a `while` loop will skip the initial permutation in any case. You want a `do`...`while` loop instead.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will run a test with it. I considered this route but I thought that it would first give all permutations of letter_box_a with only the initial permutation  of letter_box_b, followed by all permutations of letter_box_b with only the final permutation of letter_box_a. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yeah.  `next_permutation` doesn't remember where you started, and thus doesn't know when to stop; it relies on the order of the elements in the permutation. You can permute the same group over and over, and it'll only return false each time it wraps back around to the "first". So what happens is the first group gets permuted over and over, and each time it wraps around, the second get permuted as well. Only when both permutations wrap back around does the function return false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `std::next_permutation`, you need a nested loop for each vector you are permuting:

```
std::string s0 = "ab";
std::string s1 = "cd";

do
{
    do
    {
        cout << s0 << "" << s1 << endl;
    } while (std::next_permutation(s0.begin(), s0.end()));
} while (std::next_permutation(s1.begin(), s1.end()));
```

Output:

```
abcd
bacd
abdc
badc
```

And, in the class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::string_view arg_a, std::string_view arg_b)
        : a(arg_a)
        , b(arg_b)
        , last(false)
    { }

    void reset_permutations()
    {
        last = false;
    }

    bool next_permutation(std::string& r)
    {
        if (last)
            return false;

        if (not std::next_permutation(a.begin(), a.end()))
            if (not std::next_permutation(b.begin(), b.end()))
                last = true;

        r = a + b;
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::string a, b;
    bool last;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Foo foo("ab", "cd");
    string s;
    while (foo.next_permutation(s))
        cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was also how I first approached it, maybe I am just tired but it seems like there is an issue with how does the external user of the class do something with each permutation without accessing the internals?

Comment: Since we cannot rely on yield like in Python, we have to keep a small nugget of internal state to return all of the permutations (event the first one).